# Reducing the time complexity of the program

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap, time-complexity

I am doing this practice problem where given a string `s` of lowercase letters, and a position `p`, I have to print all the occurrences of the letter at position `p` which occur before the position `p`. 
Eg: If the string is "abaac" and p=3(1 based index) then output is 1 because 'a' occurs one time before the position p.
 There are q queries each giving me a position p. Is there any way to make this code more efficient? 
I'm using hashing which is pretty efficient I think? Is there any algorithm that I am not aware of?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    int q;
    cin>>q;
    while(q--)
    {
        int p;
        cin>>p;
        int freq[26] = {0};
        for(int i = 0; i<(p-1); i++)
            freq[s[i]-'a']++;
        cout<<freq[s[p-1]-'a']<<"\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### HINT ONLY

The trick here is pre-calculate answers just after you read string. You can do it quite fast.
So in exchange of memory complexity you will gain on time complexity.
This can be done in linear time to string size.

This way you will be able to provide an answer in following queries in constant time.

### OFFTOPIC

This problem should have this code to gain on IO speed:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently does much more than necessary. In pseudo code you do

```
while(q--)
{
    read p
    freq[character] = determine count of any character up to position p
    print freq[character at position p]
}
```

You repeat the whole process of counting how often each character appears before position `p` for each single query but then you only use the information for one single character. Thats not quite efficient. Instead you should do:

```
freq[position] = determine occurences of character at each position
while(q--)
{
    read p
    print freq[p]
}
```

The first part can be done by traversing the input string once and then for each query you just have to look up the result from the table.

Comment: `freq[character][position]`?

Comment: @MarekR hm? which one?

Comment: I mean I do not see how this expression can be needed anywhere. Only one index is need character xor position.

Comment: How can I implement this? I am getting the value of ```p``` only inside the while loop.

Comment: @MarekR oh right, I assumed a 2d lookup table was needed, will fix that

Comment: @ArM thats why you calculate the result for all values of `p` in one pass through the string.

Comment: I dont have the ```[position]``` part of freq[character][position] to be able to do that outside the while loop

Comment: @ArM forget about `[character][position]` i made a mistake, only a 1d lookup table is needed. No you dont know the value of `p` but you can calculate the result for any value of `p` with a single loop over the string. Later you just have to lookup the result

Comment: Okay, will try and implement that now!

Answer (score 0):

You can compute solution once from the string before each query.
So each query in O(1).

```
std::vector<std::size_t> build_res(const std::string& s)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> res;
    int freq[26] = {0};

    for (auto c : s) {
        res.push_back(freq[c - 'a']++); // Assuming a-z contiguous (as in ASCII)
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    const auto res = build_res(s);
    int q;
    std::cin >> q;
    while (q--)
    {
        int p;
        std::cin >> p;
        std::cout << res[p - 1] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a giving a fish instead a fishing rod.

Comment: @MarekR: OP has provided each element though.